# Responsove input Icon for input type file

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have following css to my input type file where the brows button replace by an image. When i resize my screen as height and width are 40px the image is not responsive. What should need to do for re-sizing image according to reen

**CSS**

```
<style>
/*Css for upload file button*/
label.filebutton {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(/tukaiexotic/assets/img/ico/upload.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

label span input {
    z-index: 999;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -700px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    cursor: pointer;
    _cursor: hand;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="filebutton" style="text-align:center;">
  <span title="Upload Actual Image">
    <input type="file"  accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"  id="myfile" name="myfile" >
  </span>
</label>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you fiddle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

for your  `label.filebutton`

Check this out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/060sy8ht/1/) (try resizing the result frame)

Comment: Nope ! It didn't worked. If i remove height and width Image is not getting displayed.